# Metamask Ethereum Problem

Tags: ether, metamask

I had $200 worth of Ethereum and randomly, it got sent to a random account. I didn't noticed this a week after, I was wondering if it is suppose to take some Ethereum, but not all?

Comment: It looks like your account has been compromised. Perhaps you shared your seed phrase unintentionally with another party.

Comment: don't send any more ether again to your current metamask. You should change the seed phrase, which will generate new accounts (Take care don't copy your new seed phrase from ganache or any other place) and make sure you are using the original metamask and not a fake clone.